# Proving property of group-like algebraic structures by means of induction

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, induction

How do you prove (by means of induction) that the following is true for all group-like algebraic structures?

$$\operatorname{ord}(a_1 \circ a_2 \circ a_3 \circ \cdots \circ a_{n-1} \circ a_n) = \operatorname{ord}(a_2 \circ a_3 \circ \cdots \circ a_{n-1} \circ a_n \circ a_1)$$

where ord refers to the order of the group.

Comment: what's a group-like algebraic structure ? is $a_1$ a group ?

Comment: a group-like algebraic structure is an algebra, that satisfies certain conditions. An algebra has a set of values and operations, $a_1$ is an element of the set of values.

Comment: well that didn't clarify anything. Also are you talking about the order of the group or about the order of a value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a_1a_2 \dotsb a_n)^{m+1} = a_1(a_2 \dotsb a_na_1)^ma_2 \dotsb a_{n-1}$ is all you need.